dotnet build on Linux fails with "The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly"
I'm trying to run a simple .Net program on Linux. (Raspberry Pi). 
I've installed .NET on the Raspberry Pi.
My Program.cs is only a couple of lines:
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
Console.Read();

Since I'm working on the project on both my Windows machine and the Raspberry Pi, I've added two runtimes to my solution file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Now when I want to build the solution for Windows, on Linux, it works fine:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/testproject $ dotnet build testproject.csproj

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
testproject -> /home/pi/Documents/testproject/bin/Debug/net8.0/testproject.dll

However, when I want to build it for linux, on linux, it fails:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/testproject $ dotnet build testproject.csproj --runtime linux-x64
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly. [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: A positive capacity must be specified for a Memory Mapped File backed by an empty file. [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FileStream fileStream, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, HandleInheritability inheritability, Boolean leaveOpen) [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateAppHost>b__1() [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.RetryUtil.RetryOnIOError(Action func) [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResourcesFrom, Boolean enableMacOSCodeSign) [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]
/home/pi/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(709,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(TaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/home/pi/Documents/testproject/testproject.csproj]

Build FAILED.

I haven't been able to find any meaningful info on this error, or why it should happen when running dotnet build. 
Am I doing something wrong?
Or missing something?
Cheers,
CJ
EDIT:
I tried running the command using sudo, but that threw an error:
sudo: dotnet: command not found. 
However, when I run it under su, it does compile.
So it seems to be a permissions problem.

I was under the misconception that compiling for Linux would create a different sort of file, not a dll. However that's not true.
Even when compiling for Linux it will create a DLL that I can run with dotnet.
